# Click event is not triggered in Nightwatch.js on MacBook using Chrome

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

As a relatively new guy in nightwatch.js and in test automation using javascript i am facing many problems which i solved somehow, but now i am faced with one problem that i am not yet able to fix it.

The thing is next, nightwatch is able to locate the element as visible but it's not able to click on it. And this is only happening on MacBook, also i have to mention that on windows environment everything is working as expected.

The things i have tried so far are:

The first solution:

```
//**expand hover menu**

 .waitForElementVisible('@hoverMenu', 1000)

.click('@hoverMenu')

//**wait one second and click on logout button**

.api.pause(1000)

.assert.visible('@logoutBtn')

.click('@logoutBtn')
```

The second solution:

```
//**expand hover menu**

 .waitForElementVisible('@hoverMenu', 1000)

.click('@hoverMenu')

//**wait one second and click on logout button**

.click('@logoutBtn',function(){

this.waitForElementVisible('@logoutBtn',10000);

this.click('@logoutBtn');

})
```

And here is the error code i am getting

> ✔ Element <#app > div > div > aside > div.header__rightbarHeader___nXVZ2 > div.radialMenu__radialMenu___2Xy3S.header__mediaMenu___3aHzZ > span> was visible after 45 milliseconds.
>
> ✖ Testing if element <@logoutBtn> is visible. Element could not be located.  - expected "true" but got: "null"

The problem is that assert is always passing and when it has to trigger the click event it will always fail.
Also strange thing is that in error message in passed test i am getting full path reported and on the failed one only '`@logoutBtn`' which is part of page object abstraction.

I am using `selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar` and the latest version of `chromedriver` available. And the site i am working on is made in `ReactJS`.

Thanks in advance guys ;)

Comment: Just to clarify; are the error messages from the relevant solutions? I.e. the `✔` is for solution 1 and  `✖` from solution 2?

Also could you post a HTML snippet for the element you're trying to act on?

Comment: Posted that message just to show that '@logoutBtn' and '#app > div > div >....' are the same element, and that element can be recognized as visible but can not trigger click. And to show when the assertion pass it will show the full xpath and when it fails it will display it as '@logoutBtn'

Comment: I must admit that I'm not entirely familiar with nightwatch or react so I'm unsure what `@logoutBtn` is doing in a selector; in xpath this is an attribute selector so are you trying to select the object with attribute `logoutBtn`? If not can you explain so I can help you to try and solve this.

Comment: '@logoutBtn' and the xpath displayed above are the same element, and the logoutBtn is short version of that because i am using page object pattern in my tests, so lets say thats some kind of abstraction of that element to avoid DRY and make my test more maintainable.
More specifically i have another JS file where i instantiated it as :

    logoutBtn: {
            selector: '#app > div > div > aside >     div.header__rightbarHeader___nXVZ2 >     div.radialMenu__radialMenu___2Xy3S.header__mediaMenu___3aHzZ > div.radialMenu__secondaryButtons___2JjrL > div:nth-child(1) > div'
        },

Comment: @timetraveler90 why aren't we just using class name here as the locator rather than full traversal of the DOM? You can give a try in browser console once that if this xpath is even correct: can do this by launching your app and typing this in console: $x("//span[@class = 'your_class_name_here']")

Comment: here is the response from the console i am getting https://s29.postimg.org/mnivo70wn/Screen_Shot_2017_01_20_at_10_30_08_AM.png @Smriti

Comment: and is there a button class inside this span (for the logout button which you are trying to click)? if this is the button, it should work smoothly. Any screenshots you got for failures?                                                                 p.s: You can ask your devs to put a unique id/class in the html for your ease.

Comment: Yes thats also what i did, but locating that element over ID doesn't seems to be working also, feeling really stuck on this issue. @Smriti

Comment: There is nothing inside that span, here is the picture https://s28.postimg.org/g44y7mw1p/span.jpg

Comment: @timetraveler90so if this logout button doesn't have any unique id/class or it cannot be added, do you know at what child index position would this element lie always..as in here https://s29.postimg.org/mnivo70wn/Screen_Shot_2017_01_20_at_10_30_08_AM.png  , you sent 4 spans with same class name

Comment: it always will be at 2nd child index position @Smriti

Comment: then just use this as the css selector in your page:

elements: {
  logoutBtn: {
    selector: '.material-icons
    radialMenu__btnIcon___3fNWR iconButton__iconButton___clsLX:nth-of-type(2)'
  }
}

and it should work!!

Comment: tried it also but still that solution doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the screenshot of the code that has to be clicked https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH9bf.jpg

And the code:

```
<span data-react-toolbox="font-icon" class="material-icons    
radialMenu__btnIcon___3fNWR iconButton__iconButton___clsLX" 
data-event="click focus" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
<!-- react-text: 211 -->input<!-- /react-text -->
</span>
```